# How can we get varying query parameters in the Rest endpoint URL?

Tags: api, rest, mule-esb

For example, if I want to have a single endpoint for all the requests, what is the best practice to design the API endpoint?

For example, instead of having three different endpoints

http://localhost:8080/api/reports/subreport1?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3

http://localhost:8080/api/reports/subreport2?param1=1

http://localhost:8080/api/reports/subreport3

I want to have one endpoint

http://localhost:8080/api/reports/{subreport}/{send the varying query parameters depending on the type of report to be requested}

My question is, is it better to pass the varying query parameters in the url or pass it in the GET method body in the json format? If it is passed in the query parameters, how can I parse it and route to the correct API implementation?

thanks,
Anu

Comment: Have you tried searching for REST API design best practices? There are really useful guides available, you can learn a lot by reading a few.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is it better to pass the varying query parameters in the url or pass it in the GET method body in the json format?

This is easy to answer: GET + method body is wrong, regardless of format.  The problem here is that the method body of a GET request has [no defined semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1); you aren't guaranteed that general purpose components are going to be polite about passing the data all the way through to the origin server.  Also, trying to distinguish different resources based on the GET body is going to make a mess in your caches (for exactly the same reason - the caches won't know that the body contains identifying information).

(At some point, some of these issues will be ironed out; the HTTPWG accepted a proposal for a [safe request with a significant payload](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body/) -- it's not a standard yet, but it is expected to become one when the hard parts have been worked out.)

If you are going to use GET, then you need to encode the information into the request-target, preferably in a standardized way.  One simple answer would be to do it the way that the web does - application/x-www-form-urlencoded key/value pairs.  For example, consider a web search form with a textarea control, and on the server you parse the free text to recover the query.

> how can I parse it and route to the correct API implementation?

The usual answer is that you use a convenient HTTP library/framework to parse the URL for you, extract the free text value from it, then apply your own functions that read in the data and branch to the correct handler.

There's no magic - we can often lean on general purpose code for coarse handling of the common cases, but if we are doing something unusual then we end up rolling our own logic to bridge the remaining gap.